# MvvmCross and Tabbed Navigation - iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I want to make a Xamarin native app using tabbed navigation and MvvmCross. I am using this project as a reference:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/master/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.iOS

I got the project working and successfully added tabs to my app, however, I don't understand how its working.

On App start I load a `TabsRootViewModel` which looks like this:

```
public class TabsRootViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public TabsRootViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(navigationService));
        ShowInitialViewModelsCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowInitialViewModels);
    }

    // Init and Start are important parts of MvvmCross' CIRS ViewModel lifecycle
    // Learn how to use Init and Start at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/view-model-lifecycle
    public void Init()
    {
    }

    public override void Start()
    {
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand ShowInitialViewModelsCommand { get; private set; }

    private async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<Tab1ViewModel>());
        tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<Tab2ViewModel>());
        tasks.Add(_navigationService.Navigate<Tab3ViewModel>());
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

From my iOS project I have a `TabsRootView` which looks like:

```
public partial class TabsRootView : MvxTabBarViewController<TabsRootViewModel>
{
    private bool _isPresentedFirstTime = true;

    public TabsRootView() : base()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (ViewModel != null && _isPresentedFirstTime)
        {
            _isPresentedFirstTime = false;
            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModelsCommand.ExecuteAsync(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And then each tab looks like:

```
[MvxTabPresentation(TabName = "Tab1")]
public partial class Tab1View : MvxViewController
{
    public HistoryView() : base("Tab1View", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

So, `ViewDidLoad` calls the method `ShowInitialViewModelsCommand` on the `ViewModel` and this somehow creates tabs as I would expect and it all works correctly.

I just dont understand how or why the method `ShowInitialViewModels` inside `TabsRootViewModel` successfully adds the tabs. I can't really find any documentation out there that is up to date it seems. Can anybody explain how this is working? And if this is the correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?